# Load GLTF file that is not located in Public folder

Tags: reactjs, three.js, base64, gltf, data-uri

I found a problem that I cannot load GLTF files into a scene if I cannot place them in the Public folder in my React application. For example, I have `MyPVPanel.gltf`, and I want to load it in react app or in my npm library, or I always to be with my react components.
[image]

My questions are:

- Is this possible to import assets from a specific folder if you develop an npm package. Do packages have something like `/public` or `/assets`?
- Can I configure my own package to have such a folder with static assets?
- How to load GLTF files without a public folder. For example, we can import `.png` files without problems in react application.

Answer (score 0):

So there is a thing named [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs). You can convert small files in that format(which is basically a base64 encoded string with some metadata at the beginning of it).

> `data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>`

In my case `[<mediatype>]` is `data:application/octet-stream`.


So if you want to load small file from specific folder in you application, first of all rename your `.gltf` file into `.json`. And after importing and converting it into base64 code you can load it using [`GLTFLoader`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader) from `three.js` library.

Here is a code example:

```js
import myGLTF from './MyPVPanel.json';
```

```js
import {GLTFLoader} from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader";
import myGLTF from "./MyPVPanel.json";

const loader = new GLTFLoader();

const stringGLTF = JSON.stringify(myGLTF) // convert Object to a String
const base64EncodedGLTF = btoa(stringGLTF) // Base64 encode the String

//First part is: 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,'
const resultingDataURI = `data:application/octet-stream;base64,${base64EncodedGLTF}`;

loader.load(
  resultingDataURI,
  (gltf: any) => {
    console.log('Loaded!!!');
    this.scene.add(gltf.scene)
  },
  () => {},
  (e: any) => console.error(e)
);
}}>Load</button>
```

Comment: Note that base64 encoding can be very inefficient, and a JSON glTF file will include either external references or embedded base64 data already, meaning your mesh data might be double-encoded for double inefficiency.  Perhaps base64 encoding a *.glb file would be slightly better?